# Posting data from android to PHP

Tags: php, android

I'm using this forum for a long time, and first of all, I would like to say thanx for helping
me LOTS of times.
This is the first time that I don't find an answer, which makes me CRAAZZZY...

I'm trying to write a super simple app, which get/post data from/into a DB.
the problem is, I can't post data (get is fine). I'm using a php file, which should get the data from the Android device, and send it to the DB.
For a start, I can't post it to my php file. I've tried it ALL (that I know of).

the PHP file-

```
$test=$_POST['v']; print $_POST['v'];
```

The Java file-

public void postData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

```
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.myweb.coom/test.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("v", "123"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        httpclient.execute(post);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

when I put Log.* it shows me that everthing is ok. it seems that the PHP doesn't get any data...

EDITING ASYNTASK-----
public class Upload  extends AsyncTask{

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("UserName", "test2");
        json.put("FullName", "1234567");
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        //

        String url = "http://my WAMP server/test.php"+ 
                            "json={\"UserName\":1,\"FullName\":2}";

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes(
                "UTF8")));
        request.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            String result = "gr8 Success";
            Log.i("Read from server", result);

        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Request failed: " ,"ERR"+ t.toString());
    }

}
```

}

MainActivity-

```
public void postData(View v) { //starts on button click

    if(upload!=null){
        if(upload.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
            Log.d("postData","no need to start AsyncTask");
            return;
        }

    }
    upload= new Upload();
    upload.execute();
    Log.i("Async", "Starting...");

}
```

PHP-
                   $json=$_GET ['json'];
                   $obj = json_decode($json);

```
               $posts = array(1);
               header('Content-type: application/json');
                 echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));
```

Comment: are you trying to write to your php file dynamically with the web?  Maybe you should just make it write to the file

Comment: Run you code in the emulator and dump the traffic in wireshark. This will help you to slove your problem.

Comment: I'm writing it to a file for it self. no other stuff...
and I don't use the Emulator, I'm using a device.

Comment: You could still use [Shark for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImx2Lm4zby5zaGFyayJd) to trace your http request.

Comment: Also, how can you be sure that "everything is ok" when you're not handling your exceptions correctly? Any empty catch block for the ``ClientProtocolException``/``IOException`` will merely hide an error. :-)

Comment: you are right... I changed the code zillion times, and in those times i wrote catch as it should be... :)

Comment: Have you tested your server independently?

Comment: the server is fine, since I got data from the DB.

Comment: Whatever it means :).  How about analyzing the value returned by httpclient.execute(post)?

Comment: maby i didn't get what do you mean by test the server independetly...

Answer (score 1):

your URL domain contains 2 'o's. you should write https://www.myweb.com/test.php, not https://www.myweb.coom/test.php

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Android SDK you are using. If you are using 4.1 and above SDK please check you re making http call on secondary thread and not UI thread. Since as you haven't reported exception so you have given Internet Permission .

Comment: gave Permission. I do use 4.1. have tried to start the method onclick- is it good enough? or i actually need a different thread?

Comment: yes buddy you need a different thread .. try using AsyncTask and inside its doInbackground make http call

Comment: in the doinbackground() - wrote what i wrote on the postdata(). and in postdata() i wrote -  
      if(upload!=null){
 if(upload.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
 Log.d("postData()","no need to start AsyncTask");
    return;
   }
   
  }
  upload= new Upload(); //my AsyncTask class
  upload.execute();
  Log.i("Async", "Starting...");

Comment: posted it... Im trying to fetch data into my WAMP server, insted of trying to send it to my online server. still, nothing. I gotta say, that if I won't find a solution soon, I'll throw the computer from my balcony!!!! :) My computer asks for pitty. help HIM :)