# Android - Data doesn't get posted to PHP Script

Tags: php, android, post

Good day!

My android application needs to send `POST` data to a `PHP` script, however the script does not detect the data being sent. As I am relatively new to Java Android programming, please pardon me if I have overlooked a simple concept.

As I have never dabbled with `ajax`, I would like a solution that does not implement `ajax`, which is why the solutions in "[Get post data from Android to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793508/get-post-data-from-android-to-php)" and "[Posting data from android to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060207/posting-data-from-android-to-php)" do not comply with my desired solution.

Below is my relevant source code:

insertContact.java

```
public void sendRequest() {
    SendtoPHP sendtoPHP = new SendtoPHP();
    sendtoPHP.execute(new String[] {
            "https://a/foo.php"
    });
}

private class SendtoPHP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String text = "";

        try {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("contactNo=98765432", "UTF-8");
            String type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", type);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length()));
            OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(data.getBytes());

            System.out.println("test success!");
            // server response
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            text = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
                return text;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                return "Failed to close reader.";
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("SUCCESS!");
    }
}
```

foo.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['contactNo'])) {
        $contactNo = $_POST['contactNo'];

        //require_once 'dbHandler.php';
        //$con = new dbConnect();
        $querymysql = new mysqli("my_db_ip", "my_username", "my_password", "my_db");
        $result = $querymysql -> query("call insertContacts($contactNo)");

        if ($result) {
            echo "Insert successful!";
        } else {
            echo "Insert failed!";
        }

        $result -> close();
        $querymysql -> close();

    } else {
        echo "Hi! Welcome to foo.php. You have reached a dead end as you are physically connecting
        to our backend scripts.<br/>This page will unfortunately serve you no purpose. Sorry for the inconvenience
         caused.";
    }
```

Android Studio Console Log

```
I/System.out: test success!
I/System.out: Hi! Welcome to foo.php. You have reached a dead end as you are physically connecting
I/System.out:         to our backend scripts.<br/>This page will unfortunately serve you no purpose. Sorry for the inconvenience
I/System.out:          caused.
I/System.out: SUCCESS!
```

As we can see from the Console Log, the `POST` data is not being sent to the PHP Script as the undesired echo message appears.

Any help would be gladly appreciated! :)

**EDIT:**

I have included the stack trace of the error that surfaced after modifying my code according the @FerryBig's answer.

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://a/foo.php
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
W/System.err:     at name.calvin.testdbconnect.insertContact$SendtoPHP.doInBackground(insertContact.java:62)
W/System.err:     at name.calvin.testdbconnect.insertContact$SendtoPHP.doInBackground(insertContact.java:41)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Before your if-statement in the PHP-file, try to dump `var_dump($_POST)` in your script and see if you get anything at all. Also, try to dump `var_dump(file('php://input'))` to see if you get the data as a input stream instead of ordinary POST-params.

Comment: Your `Posting data from android to php` link does comply with your question. While using post method you have to send your data via `name value pair` as described in that link's question

Answer (score 0):

When sending data to a webserver, you should follow the [specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-8.2.1) really close. It says you should use `=` as separator for the data, while you include this in your data, you accidentally pass this through the `urlencoder`, changing the character.

By changing `urlencoder` to encode the key side (left), and the value side (right) separately, it will send the data properly.

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("contactNo", "UTF-8") 
            + "=" 
            + URLEncoder.encode("98765432", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Using your suggested answer, I get thrown this exception: 
`I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://a/foo.php` HELP!